# JUnit ApplicationContext

Tags: java, junit, crud

У меня есть класс:

```
package com.taboon.persistence;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.TODO;
import com.taboon.api.persistence.TaboonRepository;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

@Service(value = "TaboonRepository")
@Configuration
public class FileSystemRepository<PObject> implements TaboonRepository<PObject> {

    File file;
    public FileSystemRepository(File file){
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<PObject> findAll(Sort sort) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE) {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented yet");
        }
        //TODO - implement sorting
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<PObject> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        Pageable pageObject =  pageable;
        Pageable pageableObj = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < listRepository.size(); i++) {
               if (listRepository.get(i).equals(pageable)) {
                   pageableObj = pageable;
               }
            }
        return (Page<PObject>) pageableObj;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends PObject> S save(S s) {
        List pObj = listRepository;
        pObj.add(s);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(file, pObj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<PObject> pObjectList = findAll();
        Object object=null;
        for(int i=0;i<pObjectList.size();i++){
            if(pObjectList.get(i).equals(s)) {
                object = s;
                break;
            }
        }
        return (S) object;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends PObject> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> iterable) {
        List pObjectList = (List) iterable;
        for(int i=0; i<pObjectList.size(); i++ ){
            save((S) pObjectList.get(i));
        }
        pObjectList = findAll();
        return pObjectList;
    }

    @Override
    public PObject findOne(Integer integer) {
        if(!listRepository.isEmpty() && listRepository.size()>integer) {
            return (PObject) listRepository.get(integer);
        } else return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(Integer integer) {
        if (listRepository.size()<integer)
            return false;
        else return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PObject> findAll() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List pObjectList = null;
        try {
            pObjectList = objectMapper.readValue(file, List.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!pObjectList.isEmpty())
            return pObjectList;
        else return pObjectList = null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PObject> findAll(Iterable<Integer> iterable) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Integer> integerList = (List<Integer>) iterable;
        ArrayList<PObject> returnObjList = new ArrayList<PObject>(integerList.size());
        if(listRepository!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < listRepository.size(); i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < integerList.size(); j++) {
                   if (i == j)
                       returnObjList.add((PObject) listRepository.get(i));
               }
            }
        }else return returnObjList = null;
        if (!returnObjList.isEmpty() && returnObjList.size()==integerList.size())
            return returnObjList;
        else return returnObjList = null;
    }

    @Override
    public long count() {
        long count = 0;
        count = listRepository.size();
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Integer integer) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PObject pObject = (PObject) listRepository.get(integer);
        listRepository.remove(pObject);
        deleteAll();
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(file, listRepository);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(PObject pObject) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        listRepository.remove(pObject);
        deleteAll();
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(file, listRepository);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Iterable<? extends PObject> iterable) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        listRepository.removeAll((Collection<PObject>) iterable);
        deleteAll();
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(file, listRepository);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.print("[]");
        writer.close();
    }
    List<? extends PObject> listRepository = findAll();
}
```

и есть тесты к нему:

```
package com.taboon.persistence;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.taboon.api.persistence.PObject;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FileSystemRepositoryTest {

    @Resource
    FileSystemRepository fileSystemRepository;

    @Mock
    Pageable pageable;

    @Mock
    PObject pObject;

    @Mock
    List pObjectsIterable;

    @Mock
    List list;

    public void inFile(){
        File file = new File(".//src//test//objForTests.json");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List pObjectList = null;
        File file1 = new File(".//src//test//PObjects.json");
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            pObjectList = objectMapper.readValue(file, List.class);
            writer = new PrintWriter(file1);
            writer.print("[]");
            writer.close();
            objectMapper.writeValue(file1, pObjectList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void findAllSort() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void findAllPage() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        pageable = Mockito.mock(Pageable.class);
        File file = new File(".//src//test//PObjects.json");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(file, pageable);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Page<PObject> page = (Page<PObject>) fileSystemRepository.findAll(pageable);
        Assert.assertNotNull(pageable);
    }
    @Test
    public void findAllList() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        list = Mockito.mock(List.class);
        list = fileSystemRepository.findAll();
        Assert.assertNotNull(list);
    }

    @Test
    public void findAllListInteger() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        List list = fileSystemRepository.findAll();
        ArrayList<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>(2) ;
        listInteger.add(0, 0);
        listInteger.add(1, 1);
        List pObjectsIterableInt = fileSystemRepository.findAll(listInteger);
        Assert.assertNotNull(pObjectsIterableInt);
    }

    @Test
    public void findOne() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        Object pobj = fileSystemRepository.findOne(1);
        Assert.assertNotNull(pobj);
    }

    @Test
    public void count() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        List list = fileSystemRepository.findAll();
        Integer countOfList = list.size();
        Integer count = fileSystemRepository.findAll().size();
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong size", countOfList, count);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveObject() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("id","2");
        jo.put("type", "String");
        jo.put("name", "stringOb2");
        jo.put("value", "StringOb2");
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        Object pObjectSave = fileSystemRepository.save(jo);
        Assert.assertNotNull(pObjectSave);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveCollection() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        pObjectsIterable = Mockito.mock(List.class);
        Iterable<PObject> pObjectIterableReturn = fileSystemRepository.save(pObjectsIterable);
        Assert.assertNotNull(pObjectIterableReturn);
    }



    @Test
    public void exists() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        boolean existObject = false;
        pObjectsIterable = Mockito.mock(List.class);
        pObjectsIterable = (List) fileSystemRepository.save(pObjectsIterable);
        existObject = fileSystemRepository.exists(pObjectsIterable.size() - 2);
        Assert.assertTrue(existObject);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteInteger() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        List objList = fileSystemRepository.findAll();
        Integer count = objList.size();
        fileSystemRepository.delete(count - 1);
        Object obj = fileSystemRepository.findOne(count - 1);
        Assert.assertNull(obj);
    }

    @Test
    public void deletePObject() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        Object obj = fileSystemRepository.findOne(1);
        fileSystemRepository.delete(obj);
        obj = fileSystemRepository.findOne(1);
        Assert.assertNull(obj);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteIterable() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        List objList = fileSystemRepository.findAll();
        fileSystemRepository.delete(objList);
        List objListAfter = fileSystemRepository.findAll(objList);
        Assert.assertNull(objListAfter);
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteAll() throws Exception {
        inFile();
        Assert.assertNotNull(fileSystemRepository);
        fileSystemRepository.deleteAll();
        List objList = fileSystemRepository.findAll();
        Assert.assertNull(objList);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        FileSystemRepository getFileSystemRepository(){
            File file = new File(".//src//test//PObjects.json");
            return new FileSystemRepository(file);
        }
    }

}
```

и тесты выкидывают ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно необходимо указать путь к вашему конфигурационному файлу для инициализации контекста. К примеру: `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationTestContext.xml"})`, где `applicationTestContext.xml` находится в `src/test/resources/applicationTestContext.xml`